# How to display motd in gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, motd

I know that motd is displayed only in login shell console and not for gnome-terminal. But is there a way I can display it each time I launch gnome terminal with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>?

Comment: See https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?255780-How-to-get-motd-to-display

Answer (score 0):

Have you edited /etc/motd yet?

This should show in any terminal.

source: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/welcome-message-on-terminal-582616/

Comment: No i haven't  edited any thing. and according to my information motd does NOT appear when you start gnome-terminal (terminal emulator) it appears only with tty console, which is not my intention actually; currently i am asking about a way to enable motd in the gnome terminal emulator

Answer (score 0):

You can get this once a day using

Gnome Terminal > triple horizontal bars > Profiles > Unnamed (or whichever you're using) > Command > Run command as a login shell

This behaviour is implemented by `/etc/profile.d/update-motd.sh` from the package "show-motd".

A reasonable way to override the once-a-day behaviour, that is if you want the motd to be displayed every time, is to edit the file to remove the check of the timestamp on `~/.motd_shown`:
`dpkg --status show-motd` indicates it's a conffile, so your changes would be preserved during a normal update.

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
1. Go into Preferences -> Unnamed -> Command
2. Enable the radio button "Run a custom command instead of my shell"
3. Set the command to, for example:

    /bin/sh -c 'cat /etc/motd; exec /bin/bash -l'
```

After that, opening a new terminal (e.g. hitting `Ctrl-Shift-T`) will show the contents of `/etc/motd` and give you a shell prompt.

To keep this example simple, it assumes /etc/motd exists, and you want bash as a login shell. Change as needed.